# Uncaught ReferenceError: csrftoken is not defined

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a shopping cart for my website using java script and django. But when I click on the "add to cart" button, i get an error Uncaught ReferenceError: csrftoken is not defined
at updateUserOrder (cart.js:28:19)
at HTMLButtonElement. (cart.js:14:13) in console, which refers to the code X-CSRFToken :csrftoken.
file cart.js:

```
var updateBtns = document.getElementsByClassName('update-cart')

for (i = 0; i < updateBtns.length; i++) {
    updateBtns[i].addEventListener('click', function () {
        var productId = this.dataset.stuff
        var action = this.dataset.action
        console.log('productId:', productId, 'Action:', action)

        console.log('USER:', user)
        if (user == 'AnonymousUser') {
            console.log('User is not authenticated')

        } else {
            updateUserOrder(productId, action)
        }

    })
}
function updateUserOrder(productId, action){
    console.log('User is authenticated, sending data...')

        var url = '/update_item/'

        fetch(url, {
            method:'POST',
            headers:{
                'Content-Type':'application/json',
                'X-CSRFToken':csrftoken,
            },
            body:JSON.stringify({'productId':productId, 'action':action})
        })
        .then((response) => {
           return response.json();
        })
        .then((data) => {
            location.reload()
        });
    }
```

base.html:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/cart.js' %}">var user = '{{request.user}}'

function getToken(name) {
    var cookieValue = null;
    if (document.cookie && document.cookie !== '') {
        var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
        for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
            var cookie = cookies[i].trim();
            // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
            if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) === (name + '=')) {
                cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return cookieValue;
}

var csrftoken = getToken('csrftoken')
</script>
{% endblock content %}
```

button:

```
<button data-stuff="{{stuff.id}}" data-action="add" class="btn btn-outline-secondary add-btn 
update-cart">Add to Cart</button>
```

Comment: `var csrftoken` is probably not visible in `cart.js`. Without a minimal example, I can only guess - maybe try `'X-CSRFToken': getToken('csrftoken')` in `cart.js` (this still requires that `cart.js` is loaded after the inline script block)

Comment: 'X-CSRFToken': getToken('csrftoken') don't give results( 
What does it mean "cart.js (this still requires that cart.js is loaded after the inline script block) "? I'm very bad know js